# protractor expect not working for non-angular accordion widget

Tags: angularjs

After clicking on the accordion element, the accordion panel opens, but the expect() in the following code passes even though the desired panel has been expanded (aria-expanded="true").  I am trying to verify the correct panel has been opened.  I am new to protractor - any help will be appreciated.

```
var el = element(by.css('#brainstormingLink'));
el.click().then(function(){
    browser.sleep(1000).then(function(){
        expect(element(by.css('#BrainstormingAccordion[aria-expanded="false"])).isPresent());
    });
});
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<h3 id="brainstormingLink" class="menuSectionLink ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top" sectionnum="1" role="tab" aria-controls="BrainstormingAccordion" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Brainstorm</h3>
<div id="BrainstormingAccordion" class="accordion-inner scrollable ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" aria-labelledby="brainstormingLink" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; height: 282px; overflow: auto;">
    Follow these steps to brainstorm ideas:<br><br>
        <ol>
            <li>Use the add idea button <div class="toolbarButtonIcon inlineIcon"><div id="icon-plus">&nbsp;</div></div> to enter one idea, fact, or opinion about your topic that you think might be useful.</li>
            <li>Continue using the add idea button <div class="toolbarButtonIcon inlineIcon"><div id="icon-plus">&nbsp;</div></div> to add as many ideas as you can.<br><br>
                <div class="buttoncenter"><button class="btn btn-custom" type="button" name="brainstorming" title="brainstorming"> about brainstorming</button></div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test always passes because you didn't complete the assertion in the `expect` statement.  `.isPresent()` returns a boolean so you need to finish it with whatever you are expecting the result to be i.e `.toBe(false)` or `.toBeTruthy()` etc.

Just note that `isPresent` is really asking if that element is present in the page, if you want to know if it's currently visible to a user then use `.isDisplayed()`.  Also, since that element has an ID, I think you're better off locating it that way like you did with the first element, the HTML attribute isn't necessary unless you had trouble locating it.  I always use ID when it's available because they're unique.

List of available assertions here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html